# How to connect mongoDB from another Machine in ASP.Net Core webapi?

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have installed mongoDB on another machine(server) and created database there, but i want to access and use that database from another machine(my laptop) creating ASP.Net Core web api project. In ASP.Net Core, to connect the database i have to add database configuration on appssetting.json file like this [image: it is the project setup to connect database locally]

but my `ConnectionString: mongodb://localhost:27017 is empty`, because i am not creating database on my machine. How can i get my address/string of my database that is on another server, so that i can use it that database and make an API?

Comment: I've changed your ASP.NET tags so they're actually for ASP.NET *Core* rather than ASP.NET *Framework*.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you're asking? It seems like you're asking us how to replace "localhost" with the hostname/IP address/DNS name for your other machine that's hosting your database.

Comment: So, I have  a server that runs on windows os. it has an IP of course, and I installed and created mongoDB on that server. I am creating ASP.NET Core web api project on my laptop(Mac), following the doc of ASP.Net Core web api, I came to know that we connect to mongoDB database locally right?, but I want it to connect the database which is created on my server. and I dont know if mongoDB created on my server locally or I can use just as you said with IP, I am little confused about it